# Read a string and use it to read another file's variable's value

Tags: python, file, variables

I'm using Python 3.3.2, and I'd like to have my code take a string, and use it to find a variable with the same name in another file.

E.g.

File1.py contains:

```
global A1
A1 = ['Plain']
global A2
A2 = ['Beach']
global A3
A3 = ['Swamp']
```

and File2.py contains:

```
import File1
coords = A1
location = eval(coords)
```

but no matter how I format what I have; I always get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python/evaltest.py", line 2, in <module>
    startLocation = A1
NameError: name 'A1' is not defined
```

I know that the error itself is an ordering problem, but I don't know how I would call the variable before I tell it the string?

Comment: Try `coords = File.A1`, but using `eval` is a bad idea. And you don't need to use `global` in global scope.

Comment: You should really take some time to read about the things you're doing. First of all, your `global` statements have absolutely no effect whatsoever. Second, you don't seem to understand the way importing works. Third, __DON'T USE EVAL__ - for dynamic variable access, you want to use `globals()` or `getattr` or a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary in File1, and then just gather it in File2

File1 Contents:

```
d = {'A1':['Plain'], 'A2':['Beach'], 'A3':['Swamp']}
```

File2 Contents:

```
from File1 import d
coords = 'A1'
location = d[coords]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to do `coords = File1.A1`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
coords = File1.A1
```

The reason is that python accesses this variable referring to the filename.